# Selenium - click does not trigger any action nor throws exception

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver and java and I need to click on this element:

here is the code:

```
driver.get(urlHp);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
By btn = By.cssSelector("#_content-it_it_jcr_content_home-par1_promo_-par_o > div > li> a> div.btn-wrapper > button".trim());
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(btn));

driver.findElement(btn).click();
```

I can get the element and do not throw any exception but the click does not work.

Please note that the element is below the viewport.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Javascript executor:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(btn));
```

Comment: thank you! could u also explain it a bit more please?

Comment: hope it helps https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try with Actions class as given below.

```
driver.get(urlHp);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
By btn = By.cssSelector("#_content-it_it_jcr_content_home-par1_promo_-par_o > div > li> a> div.btn-wrapper > button".trim());
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(btn));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement btnElement=driver.FindElement(btn);
actions.MoveToElement(btnElement).Click(btnElement).Perform();
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting this: The method moveToElement(WebElement) in the type Actions is not applicable for the arguments (By)

Comment: thank you I already accepted the other answer but still give u a +1 for your time

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can only click **visible elements**. By this I mean, that it should work as a user would use your app.
What Ranjith's showed you:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(btn));
```

This is clicking the button with actual javascript code. For a quickfix this is fine. But remember that this implementation will also click the element if it's size is 1px by 1px. Test will pass, but your app is not usable.
I would rather recommend for selenium to use scrollIntoView method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

This way you are closer to the actual user flow.

Comment: Actually a better example would have been css display: none. :)